# Why is Period not Comparable

Tags: java, date, comparison

Why does `java.time.Period` not implement the `java.lang.Comparable` interface?

Simple question, but the answer may not be as simple: The other commonly used temporal amount `java.time.Duration` *does* implement `Comparable`, so I assume the designers probably will have thought about it, but decided against it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because only months can be `normalized()`, not days. I.e. `P30D` may be smaller, equal, or larger than `P1M`, depending on whether it's being applied to a, e.g., January, February, or March.

Actually, `equals` doesn't do any normalization, so `P30D` is not equal to `P1M`. Even `P1Y` is not equal to `P12M`, which may be surprising.

If you need to compare periods, you'll need a way to handle that – in some cases – you can't decide. Or you use standard months of 30 days, which is a common simplification in fiscal computations.

BTW: This should really be in the JavaDoc of `Period` and `#normalized()`.